# Visualizer onFftDataCapture - how to interpret?

Tags: android

Android Visualizer callback onFftDataCapture provides a byte array of fft data. Is the data paired as real-byte/imaginary-byte? I am wondering if the following pseudo-code is correct?

```
for(int i=0;i<fft.length;i+=2) {
  byte real = fft[i];
  byte imag = fft[i+1];
  long magnitudeSquare = real*real + imag*imag;
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Question: what frequencies does the array represent? There are 1024 bytes received in the callback... I'm assuming each index stands for a particular frequency, but not sure which. How do we figure that out? Is there a multiplier or something? Or is it simply `index = frequency`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those interested, my logic seemed to be correct as I see my meter move in synchronization with the loudness of the speaker. I am marking this as correct answer for lack of a more authoritative answer.

Regards,
Peter

Answer (score 0):

This works for me using Xamarin Studio.  Adapt as needed.
Keep in mind that the real and imaginary data is actually a signed byte.
This conversion will get you a normalized -1 -to- +1 range for the Pythagorean magnitude.

```
public void OnFftDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] bytes, int samplingRate)
{
    float[] fft = new float[bytes.Length/2];
    for(int i=0;i<fft.Length;i++)
    {
        float real = (float)(sbyte)(bytes[(i*2)+0])/128.0f;
        float imag = (float)(sbyte)(bytes[(i*2)+1])/128.0f;
        fft[i] = ((real*real)+(imag*imag));
    }
}
```